# Codeigniter ION auth unique group login form

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I am new in ION-Auth, I want to make admin panel unique login form where admin can only login (no other user groups can allows to login here) and one for unique login form for employee group where employee can login only.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried, make two different view each for single group For example group A and group B contain group_a_view.php and group_b_view.php ad controller auth_group_a and auth_group_b. 

Each group can login only if they choose url auth_group_a for group a login and auth group b for group b login.

When group b try to login by group a url then after login successfully. we check whether logged in user group b then logout oser and give then message for try again.

Comment: That is the code you should post in edited question.
Post controller code, and view code you are using in certain request to let us understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say Group A is the Admin.

In the Group A controller, allow everyone to login first so you are able to check in what group that user belonged to.

Right after logging in, check if the user is an admin so he can access the Group A panel. You can check if the current user is admin by call thie is_admin metho

```
if($this->ion_auth->login($email, $password, $remember))
{
  // It means the user has logged in. He has the correct user/pass
  // Check if he is an admin

    if(!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {    // Log out if not
         $this->ion_auth->logout();
    }

    else
    {
       // Allow the access to the Group A pages
    }
}

else
{
  // Show the form again
}
```

Comment: This is one of the way, but this is not proper way, we can say.

Comment: I can't think of a solution on how would you determine a user's group if you wont allow them to login first. Well, great if you have a solution as i also need it.But this is my only solution that i could think.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help,

I am still finding good solution then current.

I will definitely, give you solution in case of I get anything.